# Can't run Kotlin project (no Run menu)

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I create Kotlin/Gradle project like this:

[image]

Then I create `src.main.kotlin.Main.kt` class with `main` method

[image]

But I cant' run it. No found menu **Run** in context menu

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
class Main{
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

Remove `class Main` in the top of file Main.kt